# Date For date created and date last updated for mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I have entered a table in MySQL using PHP with the following code:

```
`DateCreated` datetime NOT NULL,
`DateLastUpdated` datetime NOT NULL,
```

It's wasn't working it showed 0's on the date and time, I am trying to find out how to change it to `CURRENT_DATE()` to record the date only without the time, how can i do that to make the DateCreated record the date of submit, And DateLastUpdated record the date of the update. It's my first database, and couldn't work this out, Can someone please help. Thanks

Comment: Put some code .. !!

Comment: Please show us the insert code

Comment: What is the PHP code you have used to insert the Current date to DB?

Comment: <?php // ADD_DBTABLE.PHP
include('config.php');
mysql_select_db ("bkadmin_RH_FORM", $dbc);
$sql = "CREATE TABLE RHD_FORM ( 
`ID` Varchar(45) NOT NULL,
`Age`int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
`Email` DECIMAL(7,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT 99999.99,
`PhoneNumber` varchar(120) NOT NULL, 
`DateCreated` datetime NOT NULL,
`DateLastUpdated` datetime NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`ID`) 
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

if (mysql_query($sql,$dbc)){
echo "Table Created Successfully.";
} else echo "Tables Already Exit";
mysql_close();
?>

Comment: Your code is for creating a Table in DB, so what problem you face in that?

Comment: The `DateCreated`, And `DateLastUpdated` was showing 0000000, And I want now to record the date only, what do I need to do to change it.

Comment: @Noman Why do you keep putting "Look like this" as the comment to your edits...clarify what you changed (ie. Grammar/Noise Reduction/Formatting...etc)

Answer (score 0):

As far i understand your question, you need to use

`TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

If timestamp column is defined as `NOT NULL`, MySQL stores current timestamp in the column if you did not assign a value or if it has a value of `NULL`

Comment: TIMESTAMP as I understand it from my search is for the date and time, but I am looking for the Date only.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood, you want an `DateCreated` and `DateLastUpdated` column with just the date? Then you should use `date` as the type for the column. `datetime` always has the time included.

When you have done that, you can use the `CURRENT_DATE()` method as the default value for the `DateCreated` column.

For the `DateLastUpdated` you will need a trigger as the following:

```
DELIMITER $$

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS new_schema.my_table_BEFORE_UPDATE$$
USE `my_schema`$$
CREATE DEFINER = CURRENT_USER TRIGGER `my_schema`.`my_table_BEFORE_UPDATE` BEFORE UPDATE ON `my_table` FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.DateLastUpdated = CURRENT_DATE();
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

You will need to replace `my_table` and `my_schema` with the correct names for your schema and table.

Hope this works.

Comment: What is my_schema?

Comment: The name of the database. (If you dont know the name, it should be defined in the config.php which is included in your code.)